# Upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade

When I search how to upgrade my OS from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 LTS, I see posts stating to enter the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I have also seen suggestions to use software updater and select the upgrade option. Do these two methods serve different functions or are they the same thing? If they are the same thing, if I use the command-line method, will using the GUI method cause issues?

Comment: You can't do a release upgrade with the commands you posted. See Q&A I linked to.

Answer (score -1):

Just read through all the posts, and maybe google "is using terminal to update better than software updater on linux?". I would go with whatever one has more posts about